# Cannot save new customer details in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I can't register new customer in magento 2 because of this following error.

```
Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.
```

I changed `php_value max_input_vars` value to 10000 but still the error exists. Is there any other solutions for this problem

Comment: *Sounds* like a session problem - the form key is stored in your session and dropped into any given HTML form (e.g. the Admin login page). The value from the form and your session are compared when the form is submitted, to prevent CSRF attacks... if those values don't match, you get that *Invalid Form Key* error. I doubt this has anything to do with `max_input_vars`.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Change `max_input_vars` to 100000

```
max_input_vars = 100000
```

2 - Try to clear the cache from var/cache directory.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

3 - Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.